# CSS Sprite Not Working in CodeIgniter Submit Button

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, css-sprites

I am trying to do two things:

1. Replace a regular submit button in my CodeIgniter view (see code below) with a sprite button with roll over effects.
2. Submit my CodeIgniter form

> ```
> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="button" />
> ```

My sprite images (normal and hover states) both do not display using the code above. However, if I comment it out, and replace it with the following, it displays correctly, however I cannot submit my form:

```
 <p class="button"><a href="#null"></a></p>
```

Here is my css:

```
.button {
    display:block;
    width:135px;
    height: 35px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
.button a {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:transparent url(../images/button-sprite.gif) no-repeat top left;
    outline:none;
}
.button a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -35px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**SOLUTION:**
Thank you @AdityaSaxena for your alternative solution. I found another solution too:

**my.css**

```
.button {
    display:block;
    width:135px;
    height: 35px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background:transparent url(../images/button-sprite.gif) no-repeat top left; 
}

.button:hover {
    background-position: 0 -35px;
}
```

**my.html**

```
// ...
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="button" />
// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not able to submit the form because you replaced your `<input type="submit" />` with an anchor tag. You have to add the capability to submit a form to your `<a>` tag
2. `.button a` was not working because you did not have any `<a>` tag inside your `<input type="submit">` tag which is what was expected when you used `.button a`

Few changes from the html and js and things will start working for you.

Your new HTML stays intact.

```
<p class="button"><a href="#null"></a></p>
```

Your JS / Jquery if you can use it becomes this:

```
$('.button a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```